# Question about the first step inside the derivation of the Abel-Plana formula.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The derivation of the Abel-Plana formula is found [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/abelplana.pdf).

At the first step for

[image]

How does

$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\int^{{b}\pm{ih}}_{{a}\pm{ih}}\left[g(z) \pm f(z)\right]dz = 0$$

What two functions for f(z) and g(z) would cause the above limit to be 0? Does f(z) have to equal g(z)?